# Opensea not generating preview for 3d model glb

Tags: metadata, blockchain, ethereum, nft, opensea

Hope you're doing well.
I am a developer and have a query regarding my 3d model preview on opensea testnet.

I have created a metadata file https://pattirose.growwithsabrina.org/nft/1.json
using pinanta server for hosting the glb file. Opensea failed to fetch the model for  preview.

Alternatively i have tried hosting the glb file on personal hosting and used the "animation_url" key in json file but that also did not work.

All the test transactions are done on rinkeby testnet.

Please guide on how to resolve this issue, really appreciate your support.
Thanks

Comment: Same issue here, I have my metadata URI and it's "animation_url" stored in ipfs, and pinned using pinata. The contract is deployed in Goerli Test Net. All the rest of the metadata shows correctly (name, image, attributes, etc) except for the `animation_url`. I haven't found any examples in [testnets.opensea.io](https://testnets.opensea.io/) that could display the glb properly, they all have the same issue. Checked in the browser console and the request for the glb appears (blocked:scp) whereas in [opensea.io](https://opensea.io/) they show correctly.

Comment: @Marcel i couldn't find glb on opensea mainnet that are being previewed can you share some examples. On [collection page](https://opensea.io/collection/usako-chan-3d-collection) they are visible but when i view [asset page](https://opensea.io/collection/usako-chan-3d-collection) they don't render.

Comment: It seems it depends on the day, sometimes they show and some others not: https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e/105652905984981711355387048174102533489553866874432653063576599414740768260146

Answer (score 4):

*This doesn't answer OP question about glb files please check out comments.*

The problem seems not to be with opensea. Although opensea testnet sometimes does take time fetching your image from metadata but in your case its different.
The animation_url in your metadata should actually render the 3d model, animation or whatever it is.

`https://pattirose.growwithsabrina.org/nft/1.json`
The animation_url in above metadata link you provided does not render anything.
You may try re uploading it to Pinata and mint again or using [Areware.org](https://www.arweave.org/) instead of Pinata if it does not work for you.

Here is a [sample](https://arweave.net/rU5rXRqzRatOuIj5lQGjoe87SvbBuog1n-VI2Eghoa0) metadata uri, you can check that if you redirect to animation_url provided in the metadata it does render the clip in browser

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer, your metadata URI contains a clip, what @Ali Raza wants to show is a glb file, which can't be previewed on a browser.

Comment: [model-viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/) perhaps this can help suggesting to set `animation_url` to html that uses model viewer.

Comment: [Metadata-Standard](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards) `animation-url` does support html

Comment: Good idea, it didn't work for me sadly.
The ipfs url shows the viewer with the glb, but when I go to the viewer in OpenSea it shows a broken link and the message "This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.". The console shows status (failed) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CSP